# Matlab proxy class issue.  (re: dependent properties)

Tags: oop, class, matlab, proxy

Consider the following Matlab (2009a) classes:

```
classdef BigDeal < handle
    properties
        hugeness = magic(2000);
    end
    methods
        function self = BigDeal()
        end
    end
end


classdef BigProxy < handle
    properties(Dependent)
        hugeness
    end
    properties(Access = private)
        bigDeal
    end
    methods
        function self = BigProxy(bigDeal)
            self.bigDeal = bigDeal;
        end
        function value = get.hugeness(self)
            value = self.bigDeal.hugeness;
        end
    end
end
```

Now consider the following use of them:

Setup:

```
>> b = BigDeal

b = 

  BigDeal handle

  Properties:
    hugeness: [10x10 double]

  Methods, Events, Superclasses
```

OneLayer:

```
>> pb = BigProxy(b)

pb = 

  BigProxy handle

  Properties:
    hugeness: [10x10 double]

  Methods, Events, Superclasses
```

TwoLayers:

```
>> ppb = BigProxy(pb)

ppb = 

  BigProxy handle with no properties.
  Methods, Events, Superclasses
```

**Question:** Why is my double layered proxy unable to see the `hugeness` when the single layer can?  Dependent properties can be calculated - but does this go only one layer deep for some reason?

---

**Update:** See my answer below for workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is two-fold:

1. The `BigProxy` object constructor is designed to accept an input object that has a (non-dependent) `hugeness` property (like a `BigDeal` object), which the `BigProxy` object can then access to compute the value for its own dependent `hugeness` property.
2. You are passing a `BigProxy` object to the `BigProxy` constructor when you create `ppb`, and you apparently can't compute a dependent property from another dependent property. For example, this is the error that is thrown when I try to access `ppb.hugeness`:

   ```
   ??? In class 'BigProxy', the get method for Dependent property 'hugeness'
   attempts to access the stored property value.  Dependent properties don't
   store a value and can't be accessed from their get method.
   ```

   In other words, the outer `BigProxy` object tries to compute the value for its dependent `hugeness` property by accessing the stored value of `hugeness` for the inner `BigProxy` object, but there is no stored value since it's a [dependent property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brh76wy-1.html#brh76wy-1_2).

I think the fix for a situation like this would be for the `BigProxy` constructor to check the type of its input argument to make sure it is a `BigDeal` object, and throw an error otherwise.

Comment: I think I agree with your analysis... although I find it annoying that I should be artificially blocked from creating a proxy to a proxy.

Comment: This is reminiscent to how Matlab won't call the overloaded `subsref` method from within other class methods. This seems like a similar restriction that's in place for similar reasons, I imagine.

Answer (score 4):

Gnovice provided a good answer to the question "why," thus I awarded him the green check of glory.  However, for those wanting a work around, you can do something like this:

```
classdef BigDeal < handle
    properties
        hugeness = magic(10000);
    end
    methods
        function self = BigDeal()
        end
    end
end


classdef BigProxy < handle
    properties(Dependent)
        hugeness
    end
    properties(Access = private)
        bigDeal
    end
    methods
        function self = BigProxy(bigDeal)
            self.bigDeal = bigDeal;
        end
        function value = get.hugeness(self)
            value = self.getHugeness;
        end
    end
    methods(Access = private)
        function value = getHugeness(self)
            if isa(self.bigDeal,'BigProxy')
                value = self.bigDeal.getHugeness;
            else
                value = self.bigDeal.hugeness;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

which will allow you to do the following

```
>> b = BigDeal;
>> pb = BigProxy(b);
>> ppb = BigProxy(pb);
```

And each of {`b`,`pb`,`ppb`} will all have the same public methods and properties.  The only drawback is that I have had to (unnecessarily IMHO) clutter up BigProxy with a new private getter.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the isa() test in getHugeness. It can simply be "function value = getHugeness(self); value = self.bigDeal.hugeness;". Once you're outside the get.hugeness Dependent property getter, it seems like the .-reference syntax no longer bypasses the getter. I agree - this extra clutter is a bummer. It might be tricky for Matlab to do otherwise, though, since avoiding it would need some special magic in the getters that treated . differently when applied to the input parameters vs any other variable of the same type.

Comment: No, wait - it should be easy. Matlab could just treat .-reference of a dependent property in the getter the same as everywhere else instaed of raising this special error. If called on self, then you'll get infinite recursion and blow the stack, and Matlab could slap the "dependent property called from its own getter" message on the end of the infinite-recursion error as a diagnostic aid. If called on another object of the same type, its getter would be called in turn, and in the case of something like BigProxy, eventually get a real value.